Grails 3: Deployment fails on tomcat 8.5 but it works perfectly on localhost
I'm currently getting the following error when I deploy to my tomcat 8.5 server:

Forwarding to error page from request [/] due to exception [Could not resolve view with name 'emoney' in servlet with name 'grailsDispatcherServlet']

I tried checking my UrlMappings to ensure that the naming scheme is all correct and I have the following:
class UrlMappings {

    static mappings = {
        "/$controller/$action?/$id?(.$format)?"{
            constraints {
                // apply constraints here
            }
        }

        //"/"(view:"/index")
        "/"(controller: "public", action: 'emoney')
        "500"(view:'/error')
        "404"(view:'/notFound')
        "403"(view:'/error403')
    }
}

class PublicController {
def emoney(){ }
}

grails-app/
└── views/
    └── public/
        └── emoney.gsp

And the view is in my public folder. Noting that this issue is not exclusive to this view, it's for every view on the system. It works fine on localhost though.

I tried to explicitly  render the view and nothing.
I have also tried cleaning and rebuilding the project several times, i tried restarting the tomcat machine, all to no avail.
I made sure my paths did not contain any white space.

Note that this project has been regularly deployed onto tomcat and it's been working just fine, but from my deployment on Friday to this Monday, it has started to present this error and I'm unsure as to where I should even be looking to solve the issue.
PS: My Tomcat is on a windows server.

Show your build.gradle file please. Is there apply plugin:"org.grails.grails-gsp" ?
